# spawn enemy from the side Sprite-kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on my game but I face a problem when I try spawn the enemy from the said I can spawn them only from the top and bottom of the scene I don't know why

This is my timer:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    initialzeGame()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

And this is the rest:

```
func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum + secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
}

func spawnEnemy() {
    //supposed to pick random point within the screen width

    let Pos = randomBetweenNumbers(0, secondNum: frame.height )
    //let PosTwo = randomBetweenNumbers(0, secondNum: frame.height )

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "zombie") //create a new enemy each time
    enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(Pos), self.frame.size.width/16)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
    enemy.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 70)
    let enmyact = SKAction.moveTo(hero.position, duration: 2)
    enemy.runAction(enmyact)
    addChild(enemy)
}
```

Comment: are you sure the enemy is not just spawning in an area that is being cropped,  also, you want to use frame.width, not frame.height, since height > then width, your enemies again are in an area that is not on screen

Comment: @AliMahdi  This : `enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true` in conjunction with this : `enemy.runAction(enmyact)` will produce very weird results. I am not sure how you didn't noticed that already by yourself ? Enemy has a dynamic body, affected by gravity, means, the physics world will apply certain force to this body (and pull it in certain direction). Also, at the same time, you are using `SKAction` to move enemies where you want. This will break physics simulation, and you will have a buggy enemy movement. I guess, you want to make enemies unaffected by gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the arguments in `CGPointMake`.

```
  enemy.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/16, CGFloat(Pos))
```

Comment: This means that the enemy posiition is statically on self.frame.size.width/16,  his comment says he is looking for `//supposed to pick random point within the screen width`